# Regex for Special Characters, Number, and letter

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex expression  that matches forward slash, number and letters
for example: a regex that matches 03/89/040/00293/AM13

i am new to java so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Regex is not only Java tool. Anyway can we see your attempt to solve this task? What problem do you have with it?

Comment: no i just googled around a bit but its very confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is: `[/\p{Alnum}]{20}`

More info:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

http://regular-expressions.info/

Comment: thnx pal 
worked for me

also can you add to above regex that matches length of 20 charachters

Comment: sure, and can you click on "accept as answer"? :-)